# #frame driver not tracking frame

Tags: drivers

I'm using the #frame driver on a value node and it keeps staying on 0 and never updating. I have restarted the blend file and reloaded scripts multiple times but still nothing.is there a fix for this?

Comment: which node are you using #frame

Comment: value node. but i just figured out the solution

Answer (score 1):

i needed to delete the value node and add another one but my playhead needs to be on frame 0 while adding it and then #frame will work

Comment: you might be fallen in the trap i falled in often - the first time you add value you have to write "#frame"...but if you then change this e.g. to "frame/10", you have to write it without hashtag. But for sure your playhead has nothing to do with it....

Comment: wooot i didn't know that! amazing! thanks for the info chris!

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie As Chris said... that's because hashtag is a command for "add new driver", and what you put afterwards is the formula. So after the field is initialized as driver, you can write anything as if you were editing a driver - but without the hashtag, since it already is a driver. You could also enter #100 and it is a driver with the value 100 (okay, doesn't make sense without variable, but anyway). Or instead of right-clicking and choosing _Add Driver_ you could enter a hashtag without anything else really and you have created an empty driver like you would with the context menu.